# NGINX rewrite broke index

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting

I have an NGINX rewrite that looks like this:

```
 if ( $uri !~ ^/(index\.php|index|css|img|fonts|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|slick) ) {

            rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php;
    }
```

Basically it's supposed to remove .php extensions from all files that are not contained in css, img, fonts etc. It works fine, but this prevents my `index.php` file from showing when accessing `/`. To me, these rewrites are complete chinese, therefore, i cannot figure it out. Can anyone tell me, why this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably rewriting `/` to `/.php`. You could make your rewrite a little more selective with:

```
rewrite ^(/.+)$ $1.php;
```